# Logout not redirecting to Login Page MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logout

I am trying to navigate to login Page(SSO) but i am facing some challenges.

I dont have any Login Page/Controller where i can navigate on logout i need to redirect to third party page(SSO) on logout.

In View :(_Layout.cshtml)

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")">
<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
<span data-i18n="Log Out">Log Out</span>
</a>
```

In HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
  // Delete the user details from cache.
  HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
  return Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogOutUrl"]);
}
```

In web.config:

```
<add key ="LogOutUrl" value="https://ssointrad.dev.ipc.us.aexp.com/SSOI/request?request_type=un_logoffampsd;SSOURL=https://wpdcldwa00123.abc.xxxx.com/GPATdev"/>
```

Now when click on logout it redirects to :
https://wpdcldwa00123.abc.xxxx.com/GPATdev/Home/Logout

How to resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should really be doing your logout via POST call not a GET.

Comment: Try fiddler ,to my assumption it is again getting redirected from the url
https://ssointrad.dev.ipc.us.aexp.com/SSOI/request?request_type=un_logoffampsd;SSOURL=https://wpdcldwa00123.abc.xxxx.com/GPATdev

Comment: Can ampersand(&) be a issue i am writing as ampsd; as web.config gives error for & ?